# Threads with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

Disclaimer: I'm definitely a Tensorflow / Keras beginner, so apologies if this should be clear from the docs or is a nonsensical question.

Basically, I am looking to run multiple Tensorflow threads in parallel while using a single instance of the model in order to process jobs from a Redis queue.

So I had something like:

```
from models import SomeModel
model = SomeModel()

def run():
    while True:
        item = my_redis_connection.zpopmin('someKey')
        if len(item) > 0:
             # process the job

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I initially was trying to run multiple tmux sessions, but immediately ran into out of memory errors, so then attempted to use python threading like

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread_one = threading.Thread(target=run)
    thread_two = threading.Thread(target=run)

    thread_one.start()
    thread_two.start()
```

but got a `Tensor Tensor("concatenate_6/concat:0", shape=(?, ?, ?, 2), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph` error.

Is there a way to do what I'm describing? Or do I just need more GPUs to be able to run in parallel tmux sessions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
def run():
    with graph.as_default():
      while True:
        item = my_redis_connection.zpopmin('someKey')
        if len(item) > 0:
             # process the job
```

Also you don't really need 2 GPUs for 2 sessions, you can just set the gpu ram to be use by TF using

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.5  # here
set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```

The 0.5 means half of the ram will be use by this session.

BTW if your goal is to make it run faster then having only one graph wouldn't really faster even if you use multithread. I think you should use separate session in that case.

Comment: Thanks Natthaphon! Specifying RAM allotment is good enough for my use case. I'm curious if you could elaborate on the session setup though -- I tried to use tensorflow sessions but ran into a ton of issues

Comment: You mean the last paragraph? I meant if you want to connect your model to multiple cameras, using multiple .py files with one model and one camera in each file should run faster than use only one file and multithread, if the model doesn't use 100% gpu.